# Python Pickle Yielding EOF Error on Read and Not Reading Correctly

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to pickle a patient object by using:

```
theFile = open(str(location)+str(filename)+'.pkl','wb')
pickle.dump(self,theFile)
theFile.close()
```

This works well and successfully writes to the file as desired. But! When I try to load the data from the thumb, I get an EOF error XOR it loads old data that is not present in the thumb.  I don't know where this old data is coming from, considering the pickle contains all the correct saved data...

Loading operation:

```
theFile = open('/media/SUPER/hr4e/thumb/patient.pkl','r+')
self = pickle.load(theFile)
theFile.close()
```

An example would be: I change an attribute of the desired object and save it.  The attribute is clearly saved in the pickle file, but when I reload the pickle file on another computer, it doesn't read the pickle and loads old data. I checked to see if it was reading the pickle and it is...

Are there any subtle nuances about pickles that I am missing? Or, am I just using the wrong read and write arguments for the pickle saving and loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning to self inside a method only updates what the variable `self` points to in that method; it doesn't update the object itself. To load it, instead return a newly loaded object from a classmethod or function. Try code like this:

```
import pickle
class Patient(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def save(self, location, filename):
        theFile = open(str(location)+str(filename)+'.pkl','wb')
        pickle.dump(self,theFile)
        theFile.close()

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, location, filename):
        theFile = open(str(location)+str(filename)+'.pkl','rb')
        m = pickle.load(theFile)
        theFile.close()
        return m

p = Patient("Bob")
print p.name

# save the patient
p.save("c:\\temp\\", "bob")

# load the patient - this could be in a new session
l = Patient.load("c:\\temp\\", "bob")
print l.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in binary mode. e.g.
theFile = open('/media/SUPER/hr4e/thumb/patient.pkl','r+b')

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.  For some reason, it is pulling the default patient instance from the pickle, instead of the saved instance. The data in the pickle file is correct...so where is it getting this old data? This is contained at the top of the pickle file: (ihr4e.views.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pickling the object's attributes dictionary. That worked much better. Example:

```
self.__dict__ = pickle.load(file('data/pickles/clinic.pkl','r+b'))
```